# Angularjs - How to implement getters and setters to Data Model?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I'm building a RESTful Webapp with an AngularJS Frontend. 
I'm trying to separate the Data - received via JSON - into an Object which can be passed between controllers, following this tutorial:
http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/

I'm struggling at the point "Sharing a model between controllers ".

My Problem is, that i can't reach the values from inside of the Object, and also not from the controller, which uses the Object. I 'm only able to reach the values with the {{ }} tags in the html template.

Hereś the Object:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app.admin')
        .factory('AdminEventFactory', AdminEventFactory);


    /** @ngInject */
    function  AdminEventFactory($http) {

        function AdminEvent(eventData) {
            if (eventData) {
                this.setData(eventData);
            }
        };

        //AdminEvent Objekt
        AdminEvent.prototype = {

            setData: function (eventData) {
                angular.extend(this, eventData);
            },

            load: function (id) {
                var scope = this;
                $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "http://docker-backend.test/api/events/" + id
                }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                    scope.setData(response.data);
                }, function myError(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            },


            //How to reach the values set in the load method via getter here?
            getTitle: function(){
                console.log(this.setData.title); //undefined
            }
        };
        return AdminEvent;
    }

}());
```

Here's the call from the controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app.admin')
        .controller('Admin.EventsController', AdminEventsController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function AdminEventsController( [...] , AdminEventFactory) { 

[...]

        function editEvent($eventId) {
            var event = new AdminEventFactory();
            event.load($eventId);
            console.log(event);
            event.getTitle(); //undefined
            $scope.event = event;
        }
[...]
```

In the HTML Template could the value be reached:

```
<!-- "TestTitle" -->
<div>{{ event.title }}</div>
```

The event logged via console:

```
AdminEvent {}
description: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
endDate: "2019-05-16T22:00:00+00:00"
id: 62
startDate: "2019-05-15T22:00:00+00:00"
title: "TestTitle"
> __proto__: Object
    [...]
```

I like to reach things like title via getter and setter in the controllers, in the model and not only via template tags {{ }}.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the `load` method return a promise:

```
        load: function (id) {
            var scope = this;
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://docker-backend.test/api/events/" + id
            }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                scope.setData(response.data);
                return response.data
            }, function myError(response) {
                console.log(response);
                throw response;
            });
        },
```

In the controller, use the returned promise:

```
    function editEvent($eventId) {
        var event = new AdminEventFactory();
        var promise = event.load($eventId);
        promise.then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(event);
            event.getTitle(); //undefined
        });
        $scope.event = event;
    }
```

The `.then` method of the promise waits for the data to arrive from the server before executing the `console.log` statements.